# How to display a number in an object according to its modifications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The [whole component is on this github url](https://github.com/charles7771/decrease-number-wont-work/blob/master/index.js) if necessary

I'm trying to decrease a number and display it in real time as it is decreased.

```
  const counts = {"2200": 1, "2230": 1, "2300": 3}

  const displayTimes = availableTimes.map((item) => {
    if (timeExists) {
        //should show number as it is decreasing, but will only show default, first number set
      return <span> {counts[`${item.time}`]} </span> 
    } else {
        return (
            <li onClick={ () => counts[`${item.time}`] > 1 && counts[`${item.time}`]-- }> //decreases count by 1.
                {`${item.time}`}
            </li>
        )
    } 
  }
 return (
    <div>
      <ul>{displayTimes}</ul>
    </div>
  )
```

The decreasing does work, I've tested that; showing the number as it decreases doesn't.

I tried using useState inside of this function but React won't allow me. I'm not even sure I need to use useState for this...

Comment: Is `displayTimes` used in the render/returned JSX? Components only rerender when state or props update. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. I have included the render in the edit. How could I update state/props here?

Comment: Is `counts` your "state"? If you shared a complete component's code it'd be easy to see what your state is and how to update it.

Comment: @DrewReese shared the github repo. will use your url to write posts from this point onwards

Comment: `availableTimes` (or `availableTimesJSON` in your repo) is a static imported JSON file. Each render cycle `availableTimes` and `counts` is reset from that JSON. IMO you have mixed up too much the logic of computing *what* values you want displayed and computing the rendered output at the same time. From what I can see, the only thing that'll trigger this component to rerender is when the `value` of your context updates.